# can't get a pointer on my button in a dialogfragment

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to build a simple DialogFragment which contains a textview and two buttons (send and cancel).

I want to disable the button when the textview is first empty, but the positiveButton variable in my code is always null and I get the following exception:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

This is the code:

```
public class SendFriendRequestFragment extends DialogFragment {
private TextView tvEmail = null;
Button positiveButton = null;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send_friend_request, null);

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(layout)
            .setTitle("Send request")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.send, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String email = tvEmail.getText().toString().trim();

                    if (validateInput()) {
                        SendFriendRequest(getActivity(), email);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request cannot be sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

    positiveButton.setEnabled(false); // positiveButton is null and this call raises an exception !
    tvEmail = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.email);
    tvEmail.addTextChangedListener(new InputTextWatcher(tvEmail));
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    //return builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
// Other functions that use the two variables positiveButton and tvEmail ...
}
```

Could anyone please tell me how to fix my problem and what's the best way to get a pointer of the buttons and the views contained in the used layout ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The positive `Button` won't actually be created until the `Dialog` is shown. Since you're in a `DialogFragment`, you're not handling the `show()` call on the `Dialog` directly. You could set an `OnShowListener` on the `AlertDialog`, but it's probably simpler to just get the `Button` in the `DialogFragment`'s `onStart()` method.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution was struggling grabbing the button from onBindDialogView but was perhaps too early.